# Trick matlab into thinking gpuArray is scalar

Tags: matlab

I have following function which I would like to apply to each element:

```
function result = f(a, b, bs)
    % Simplified code
    result = a
    for i=0:bs
        result = dosomething(result, b(i))
    end
end

% Use
arrayfun(@result, gpuArray(A), gpuArray(B), size(B));
```

Is there a way of 'tricking' MATLAB into thinking `b` is scalar for purpose of passing to function?

Comment: Can you be more specific? I'm not quite clear with what you want to achieve, Sorry.

Comment: @Acorbe: I have several vectors (say `A1`, `A2`, `A3`, ... `B1`, `B2, B3`, ...). I need to create vector `AR` where `AR(i)` is result of reduction involving `A1(i)`, `A2(i)`, `A3(i)`, ... over `B1`, `B2`, `B3`, ....

Comment: thus, you need kind of higher order tensor-like operation? basically, speaking in abstract, you want a tensor of order `n+1` out of operations on tensors of order `n`. Is that right?

Comment: As an example - I need to calculate `AR(i) = sum(B1 + B2 + A1(i) + A2(i))` (relationship is not linear so it is not that simple)

Comment: yeah, now I perfectly got you. I'll help you in my lunch break ;). Btw, did you try explicit vectorization (i.e. dummy cycles) before considering higher level wrapping in some  `arrayfun` function? Moreover, I guess no change can be done in your `f`, right?

Comment: @Acorbe: I have tried during my original code which was a bit slow. I haven't done it for GPU as I assumed it don't have a loop merging.

Comment: Hmm. I've managed to write code using `repmat` and `bsxfun` but I'm a bit worried that creating `MxN` matrices is suboptimal. Do you know if they are JITted away?

Comment: I would try to use `bsxfun` as much as I can. Consider [this](http://www.mathworks.se/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/312290).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do it is to use `bsxfun` function:

```
C = bsxfun(f, A, B') % A is column vector
```

is more or less equivalent to

```
C(i,j) = f(A(i,1), B(j,1))
```

Other useful function is `repmat`.

Then the series of matrices and vectors are JITted so there is in effect no `O(MN)` space penalty (checked by `nvidia-smi`).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there's currently no way to do this for two reasons: firstly, the ARRAYFUN implementation for gpuArrays always insists that inputs are either scalar or all of the same size. Secondly, the gpuArray ARRAYFUN body does not currently support either indexing or anonymous functions that refer to variables from the outer scope.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you want to do, but I suspect that you want the whole of array B to be passed into the function on each call to `result`. The best way of achieving this would be to use an anonymous function something like so (untested code):

```
arrayfun( @(a_in) result(a_in, gpuArray(B), size(B)), gpuArray(A) );
```

What this should do is to make an [anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/matlab/examples.html?file=/products/demos/shipping/matlab/anondemo.html) which only takes one argument (`a_in`), and calls `result` (actually `f` in your function header), with the full `B` array, regardless of the value of `a_in`.
So on each iteration of `arrayfun`, `result` will be called using just one slice of `A`, but the whole of `B`.

A more syntaxically explicit way of writing the above code would be as follows:

```
my_anon_fun = @(a_in) result(a_in, gpuArray(B), size(B));
arrayfun( my_anon_fun , gpuArray(A) );
```

A disclaimer: code is untested, and I have little experience with code using `gpuArray` so this may not apply.

Comment: Doesn't work - that was the first thing I've tried. Complains that anonymous functions cannot access the variables from workspace.